# How to update nested object array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to modify component state which has inner array objects. There is no problem with modifying object array but  I'd like to update inner object array *value* which has **action** format. It doesn't update the action value as *"No Action Needed"*.
What's the wrong with that `map()` functions?
Thanks in advance.

```js
let example_response = {
  data: [
    {
 
      details: [
        {
          format: "date",
          value: "2020-04-29T15:03:44.871Z",
          title: "Date"
        },
        {
          format: "action",
          value: "-",
          title: "Action"
        }
      ],
      id: 13409,
      isSelected:true
    },   {
 
      details: [
        {
          format: "date",
          value: "2019-04-29T15:03:44.871Z",
          title: "Date"
        },
        {
          format: "action",
          value: "-",
          title: "Action"
        }
      ],
      id: 13409,
      isSelected:false
    }
  ]
};
 const newList = example_response.data.map((item) => {
    if (item.isSelected) {
      item.details.map((elem) => {
        if (elem.format === "action") {
          const updatedElem = {
            ...elem,
            value: "No Action Needed"
          };
          return updatedElem;
        }       
      });
    }
    return item;
  });
console.log(newList);
```

Comment: Wand what is your problem/error message ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 2 problems:

1. You are not modifying `item.details` (you are just mapping it).
2. You only return `updatedElem` when `elem.format === "action"` but you're returning anything otherwise

Try

```js
let example_response = {
  data: [{

    details: [{
        format: "date",
        value: "2020-04-29T15:03:44.871Z",
        title: "Date"
      },
      {
        format: "action",
        value: "-",
        title: "Action"
      }
    ],
    id: 13409,
    isSelected: true
  }, {

    details: [{
        format: "date",
        value: "2019-04-29T15:03:44.871Z",
        title: "Date"
      },
      {
        format: "action",
        value: "-",
        title: "Action"
      }
    ],
    id: 13409,
    isSelected: false
  }]
};
const newList = example_response.data.map((item) => {
  if (item.isSelected) {
    item.details = item.details.map((elem) => {
      if (elem.format === "action") {
        elem.value = "No Action Needed";
      }
      return elem;
    });
  }
  return item;
});
console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already creating a new array with the top level `map` method, you can use `forEach` and assign the value.

```js
let example_response = {
  data: [
    {
 
      details: [
        {
          format: "date",
          value: "2020-04-29T15:03:44.871Z",
          title: "Date"
        },
        {
          format: "action",
          value: "-",
          title: "Action"
        }
      ],
      id: 13409,
      isSelected:true
    },   {
 
      details: [
        {
          format: "date",
          value: "2019-04-29T15:03:44.871Z",
          title: "Date"
        },
        {
          format: "action",
          value: "-",
          title: "Action"
        }
      ],
      id: 13409,
      isSelected:false
    }
  ]
};

const newList = example_response.data.map((item) => {
  if (item.isSelected) {
    item.details.forEach((elem) => {
      if (elem.format === "action") {
        elem.value = "No Action Needed";
      }       
    });
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let example_response = {
  data: [{
      details: [{
          format: "date",
          value: "2020-04-29T15:03:44.871Z",
          title: "Date"
        },
        {
          format: "action",
          value: "-",
          title: "Action"
        }
      ],
      id: 13409,
      isSelected: true
    },
    {
      details: [{
          format: "date",
          value: "2019-04-29T15:03:44.871Z",
          title: "Date"
        },
        {
          format: "action",
          value: "-",
          title: "Action"
        }
      ],
      id: 13409,
      isSelected: false
    }
  ]
};
const newList = example_response.data.map(item => item.isSelected
  ? item.details.map(elem => elem.format === "action"
    ? ({ ...elem, value: "No Action Needed" })
    : elem)
  : item.details);
  
console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not return a modified item, it just maps over the details when the item is selected. Make sure you are returning something in else clauses too. Here's an example using shorthand notation:

```
const elementUpdater = (element) => element.format === 'action' ? {...element, value: 'No action needed'} : element
const itemDetailsUpdater = (item) => item.isSelected ? item.details.map(elementUpdater) : item
```

```
example_response.data.map(itemDetailsUpdater)
```

Which yields:

```
[
    [
        {
            "format": "date",
            "value": "2020-04-29T15:03:44.871Z",
            "title": "Date"
        },
        {
            "format": "action",
            "value": "No action needed",
            "title": "Action"
        }
    ],
    {
        "details": [
            {
                "format": "date",
                "value": "2019-04-29T15:03:44.871Z",
                "title": "Date"
            },
            {
                "format": "action",
                "value": "-",
                "title": "Action"
            }
        ],
        "id": 13409,
        "isSelected": false
    }
]
```